# Amend $my_post['post_content'] to show description as well as title of the post

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

Sir, I wants to amend my **php** code so that it will show post description and post title simultaneous.

The undermentioned php code is to replace my Wordpress Post title with Coupon Title:

```
$my_post['post_title'] = str_replace("&amp;amp;", "and", $v['coupon_title']);
```

The undermentioned php code is to replace my Wordpress Post Description with Coupon Title:

```
$my_post['post_content'] = str_replace("&amp;amp;", "and", $v['coupon_description']);
```

I want customized the php to replace 
`$my_post['post_content']` with  `$v['coupon_title']` &

```
$v['coupon_description']
```

Please help ?

Comment: So you want to concatenate `$v['coupon_title']` and `$v['coupon_description']` as `$my_post['post_content']` or what?

Comment: Yes sir, you are correct that i wants to concatenate $v['coupon_title'] and $v['coupon_description']

Comment: So since you already have `$v['coupon_title'] ` as `$my_post['post_title']` then `$my_post['post_content']  = $my_post['post_title'] . str_replace("&amp;amp;", "and", $v['coupon_description']);` won't work?

Comment: Sir, how can it be possible. Pls help